# Custom Constructor wont enter for loop (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Novice here. Can't figure out why my program won't enter this for loop. I have a custom class of 'Contacts' and another of 'Phonebook'. The phonebook is an array of contacts and the issue lies in the constructor I created to read the lines from a txt file using stringstream. Once I read the lines, assign them to variables, and create a Contact object, I put a for loop to try and add them to the array. When I run the program, it never entered the for loop. Any help is appreciated! It's probably something easy, feel free to rip me apart, it wont hurt my feelings!

Phonebook class with the for loop that just wont go

```
#ifndef PHONEBOOK
#define PHONEBOOK
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include "Contact.h"

using namespace std;

class Phonebook
{
private:
    int capacity = 1000000;
    int arrSize = 0;
    Contact *array;

public:
    int count = 0;
    Phonebook();
    Phonebook(string phonebookfile)
    {
    string fname;
    string lname;
    int pNumber;
    ifstream file("phonebook.txt");
    string input;
    **while (getline(file, input))
    {
        stringstream ss(input);
        ss >> fname;
        ss >> lname;
        ss >> pNumber;
        string name;
        name = fname + " " + lname;
        Contact holder(name, pNumber);
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            {
            array[i] = holder;
            arrSize++;
            cout << arrSize;
            }
        }**
    };

};
void Phonebook::add(){
    string name;
    int number;
    cout << "Enter Name:";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter Number:";
    cin >> number;
    Contact holder(name, number);
    array[arrSize] = holder;
}
#endif
```

Contact Class

```
#ifndef CONTACT
#define CONTACT
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Contact
{
private:
    string name;
    int pNumber;

public:
    Contact();
    Contact(string name, int pNumber)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->pNumber = pNumber;
    }

};
#endif
```

How I'm calling the constructor in main:

```
#include <string>
#include "Contact.h"
#include "Phonebook.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Phonebook phonebook("phonebook.txt");
    phonebook.add();
```

Comment: You should check if the file is open before reading from it.

Comment: "it never entered the for loop" - do you know if it even entered the while loop?  All input operations should be checked... `if (std::ifstream file{"phonebook.text"}) { while (getline(file, input)) { std::istringstream ss{input}; if (ss >> fname >> lname >> pNumber) { ... } else std::cerr << "unable to parse names and number\n"; } } else std::cerr << "unable to open phonebook.txt\n";`

Comment: `array` is never initialized. `array[i]` would exhibit undefined behavior, if it's ever reached.

Comment: Please provide a sample of `phonebook.txt` or an example of its layout so your program can be fully tested with minimal effort.

Comment: Depending on your IDE of choice, if `phonebook.txt` does not exist in the correct location the `getline` call will fail.

Comment: Hey guys: Thanks, I will initialize the Array in the beginning of the function. In regards to the while loop, I know it enters it as I tested by printing the variables and they printed the correct text from the file. Lastly, I know the file exists in the folder.  The text in phonebook.txt is in this format:
PATRICIA JOHNSON 973437
LINDA WILLIAMS 3532665
BARBARA BROWN 4059171
ELIZABETH JONES 2736877
JENNIFER MILLER 3863726
MARIA DAVIS 6297086
SUSAN GARCIA 6063076

Answer (score 0):

If the "phonebook.txt" is not found, the getline won't be work.

you need to check the "phonebook.txt" exists in the same folder.

you can rewrite the code to...

```
ifstream file("phonebook.txt");
if(!file){ 
   cerr << "The file couldn't be open!\n"; 
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I will implement this. However, the file is definitely being found as I ran a quick cout test before the loop on one of the variables and the info is being passed into the first variable. The program just doesn't loop to the next line of the file.

Comment: I got it, your file "phonebook.txt" just one line. So the all info is compress in a line, and the result is correct!

Comment: you can rewrite the code to this:
getline(file, input);
stringstream ss(input);...


the “while” loop is not necessary

Comment: Another opinion, you can put "ifstream" varable into while loop, such like while(file >> variable)......